# Identity Server 4, API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint

Tags: javascript, api, jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to let an javascript client communicate with an api with the help of reference tokens. I am using Identity Server 4.

What is going OK:

On login the javascript client/webapplicatoin gets routed to Identity server for user and password validation
On success the user gets routed back to the javascript/webapplication and has a valid IdentityToken

What is NOT going OK:

When the javascript client/webapplication makes a call to my Api, the request gets received by the api. Then the api wants to check the received identity Token with Identity Server to get an access token, but fails to contact the server with te following error in the console:

> ```
> fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ApiSecretValidator[0]
>       API validation failed.
> fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint[0]
>       API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting.
> ```

Pretty clear the Api is not allowed to communicate with te server...

I think I have a configuration error somewhere but I just cant see where. Tried all kind of different set-ups, I am out of ideas to try or to change...

This is what I have untill now:

**For the javascript client:**

I use the oidc-redux package, the config I use:

```
var userManagerConfig = {
   authority: "http://localhost:50289",
   redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
   client_id : "js",
   response_type : "id_token",
   scope :"openid",
};
```

**Identity Server 4 Configs**

Client definition:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "js",
            ClientName = "my js client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            RequireClientSecret = false,
            RequireConsent = false,
            RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:3000/callback" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000" },
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,
            AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:3000" },
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "myApi"
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Api resources definition:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("myApi")
        {
            ApiSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("superweaksecret")
            }
        }
    };
}
```

in Configure service I add it all together in the container:

```
// configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
    .AddProfileService<CustomClaimService>()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

**The Api setup**

Based on .net Core, in the ConfigureService method I have the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
       options.Authority = "http://localhost:50289";
       options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
       options.ApiSecret = "superweaksecret";
       options.ApiName = "myApi";
       options.EnableCaching = false;

    });
```

Hope someone sees my error.

If I missed information or code needed for a proper awnser, please let me know.

Kind regards,
Roel

Comment: I don't understand the question. From your description (and code) your api should act as a protected resource and not as a client. In this case it is not supposed to retrieve the tokens. It is supposed to require them. Correct me if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: The setup is composed out of three parts, the javascript client, the Identity Server, and the Api.
The javascript client and the Identity server communicate as should. That means, from my webapplication I get routed to Identity Server to login and after succesfull login I have a IdentityToken.
The javascript/webapp client then requests an endpoint on the api. 
And then the error occurs, it happens when the api tries to validate/retrieve the necessary information for authentication of the client at the Identity Server.
The Api itself is not allowed to communicate with the Identity Server

Comment: OK so when are you getting this error?

Comment: I also updated the original question trying to be a bit more clear...

Comment: Do you intentionally want to do it like this? Because I see that you are requesting only the id_token from IDS (response_type : "id_token",). Why don't you request the access_token too (response_type : "id_token token")? Then you just need to send the access_token, when calling the api and you will be ok. Or if you have something else in mind.. ?

Comment: Yes it is intentional for only the id_token. I am trying to do openIdConnect Hybrid Flow
see: [IdentityServer4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html)

Quoted there:
 ""the identity token is transmitted via the browser channel, so the client can validate it before doing any more work. And if validation is successful, the client opens a back-channel to the token service to retrieve the access token.""""
Btw, thank you for helping me

Comment: You are welcome. Now for the question - HybridFlow is not designed to be used with browser based apps. Check brockallen's answer - https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/427 . I think that you are mistaken somewhere. In your case you need ot use implicit flow, and retrieve the both tokens. Hybrid flow is for server side apps (MVC, WebForms etc.)

Comment: That is a bummer. I still do not comprehend it completly.
Where exactly is the limitation? I can receive an idToken in my webapp. And as I understand, my Api client only needs to retrieve an accessToken with the help of that idToken from the identityServer. Quoted from IS4 docs:""the client opens a back-channel to the token service to retrieve the access token""
The errMsg I get "API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint" Lets me think that the Api ideed wants to retrieve the access token from the introspection endpoint, but is not allowed.
Can you explain your awnser a bit more?

Comment: But you do realize that this client is a server-side client (the one that is mentioned it the article you sent)? Did you read this - http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/introspection.html ? I don't see anywhere in your code, that you are trying to get to the introspection endpoint. This doesn't come out of the box

Comment: For IS4 A client can be a web application [terminology](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/intro/terminology.html#client)

services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication  section in my original question shows how my api is configured for using Identity Server4 (Installed nugetpackage is: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation)). As far as I see, it does somewhat come out of the box, because the api, after that small bit of code, tries to connect to the introspectionpoint when it gets a request from the webapp. (and fails with said error)

Comment: OK I give up - you are sending me a link, that you are not even reading to the end.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, First I am gonna go get some sleep, and to morrow open an other question, tackling the problem from an other angle.

Comment: what do I miss in the link I posted?

Comment: For me you are messing the idea. Get some sleep, and read carefully. But in a few words - your javascript app is a `client`, your API is a `resource`. Then read the `access_token` paragraph. `Clients request access tokens and forward them to the API.` The thing you want to achieve - sending `id_token` and then in the API request an access token based on it - it is achievable, but you need to write some custom stuff.

Comment: [reference tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html)

When using reference tokens - IdentityServer will store the contents of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier for this token back to the client. The API receiving this reference must then open a back-channel communication to IdentityServer to validate the token.

Well, I'll check back tomorrow :)

Comment: Now you are talking about reference token, but you have never specified in your client configuration that you are going to use it. The default access token type is JwT

Comment: :) But what about the second sentence of my original question....

Comment: The second sentence of your question, is not your client configuration. Now seriously - setup your client for reference token usage, and then try

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was missing "AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference," in my client config.... it is in there now. Quickly tested it, but same error. What I do notice is that the accessToken receive by the webclient, is a lot shorter, so it probably is a reference type of token. The error is still there.... :( Tomorrow I'll double check the request of the client to the api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IdentityServer expects shared secrets to be hashed.

```
new ApiResource("myApi") {
    ApiSecrets = {
            new Secret("superweaksecret".Sha512())
    }
}
```

Comment: But how does it (or you) know to use this particular hash and not, say, Sha256? Does it always use this hashing method?

Comment: I had the impression you had to define your secrets hashed as `new Secret("superweaksecret".Sha512())`. Isn't that how it works?

Comment: You can use either  IdentityServer's shared secret parser supports both SHA-256 and SHA-512.